# polar decomposition on finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space on $\mathbb{F}$ (where $\mathbb{F}$ can be either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$)
Let $A$ be a linear operator on $V$.

The polar value decomposition of $A$ is a pair on operators on $V$, $U$ and $P$
with $U$ unitary (i.e. $U^{*}U = I$) and $P$ positive.
$P$ is always unique, whereas $P$ is not

I wuould like to gain more insight about this topic. 
For example, can we say something more in the following cases:

- $A$ normal
- $A$ self-adjoint
- $A$ invertible (this is iff $U$ is unique, but i dont know how to prove it)

Answer (score 0):

You can find answers by reading this excellent wikipedia article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition

Comment: I did read it.. but it does not seem to answer this kind of questions...